# subset argument in aggregate function

Tags: r

I was getting unexpected results using the `subset` argument in the `aggregate` function, so I tried the following.

```
 > A <- data.frame( d1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), d2=c(1,1,2,2,3,3) , n=c(13,24,54,24,12,32) )
 > aggregate( A[,c("n"),drop=FALSE] , A[,c("d1","d2")] , FUN=sum )
   d1 d2  n
 1  1  1 37
 2  1  2 54
 3  2  2 24
 4  2  3 44
```

which does make sense.

```
 > aggregate( A[rep(TRUE,6),c("n"),drop=FALSE] , A[rep(TRUE,6),c("d1","d2")] , FUN=sum )
   d1 d2  n
 1  1  1 37
 2  1  2 54
 3  2  2 24
 4  2  3 44
```

which does make sense but would be a convoluted way to restrict observations.

***Shouldn't the following return the same result as above? Why doesn't it?***

```
 > aggregate( A[,c("n"),drop=FALSE] , A[,c("d1","d2")] , FUN=sum , subset=rep(TRUE,6) )
   d1 d2  n
 1  1  1 43
 2  1  2 60
 3  2  2 30
 4  2  3 50
```

Just in case subset is index-based, I tried the following, the result of which isn't intuitive either:

```
 > aggregate( A[,c("n"),drop=FALSE] , A[,c("d1","d2")] , FUN=sum , subset=1:6 )
   d1 d2  n
 1  1  1 58
 2  1  2 75
 3  2  2 45
 4  2  3 65
```

Comment: I thought `subset` was only for the formula method of aggregate. I.e. - `aggregate(n ~ d1+d2, data=A, FUN=sum, subset=rep(TRUE,6) )` works as expected. Using `subset` like you have results in just adding 6 to each `n` value (i.e. - 6 TRUE's == 6 x 1). Not sure why that happens though. It's not doing any actual subsetting though - you get the same strange result if you do `aggregate( A[,c("n"),drop=FALSE] , A[,c("d1","d2")] , FUN=sum , blah=c(1,1,1,1,1,1) )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the help file, the `subset` argument is part of the S3 method for type "formula", which you are not using.  You are using the S3 method for type `data.frame`. Your `subset` argument is therefore being passed down through in the `...` to `lapply()` and then to each call to `sum()`.  Since it is a vector of 6 `TRUE` values, you are getting 6 added to each summation.

Kind of an easy error to make, so I understand how you got here.

Looks like you will need to subset your data before passing it to `aggregate()`, unfortunately.